# Access to outer react component from referenced component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `React.Component` that renders references to others which are defined via `const`

Here is part of my code

```
const TodoList = ({data, remove}) => {
  let source = data.map((todo) => {
    return (<TodoItem todo={todo} id={todo.id} remove={remove}/>)
  }) 

  return (<ul>{source}</ul>)
}

export default class HomePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Start home page")

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

    this.getAllTasks = this.getAllTasks.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <p className={styles.welcomeText}>Thanks for joining!</p>
        <button onClick={this.getAllTasks}>Request all tasks</button>
        <button onClick={this.getSpecificTask}>Get specific task</button>
        <button onClick={this.createTask}>Create task</button>
        <button onClick={this.editTask}>Edit task</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteTask}>Delete task</button>

        <div id="container">
          <TodoForm addTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)} />
          <TodoList 
            todos={this.state.data}
            remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am facing issues after adding `TodoForm` and `TodoList`to the render. First of them is inner state of `TodoList` is undefined. By being more specific:

```
page.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at TodoList (page.js:85)
```

First of all I haven't committed enough time to find out how that's all work under the hood (have a different main tech stack and tight deadline for this app). Source code shows `data` is obtain via autogenerated reference `_ref3` that is passed from outer class.

I you see outer class defines and init the `data` structure, so `data` should be defined.

Do you see the issue I missed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay you are not destructuring properly
do it as this

```
const TodoList = ({todos, remove}) => {
 let source = todos.map((todo) => {
 return (<TodoItem todo={todo} id={todo.id} remove={remove}/>)
 }) 

return (<ul>{source}</ul>)
}
```

You are passing prop as todos and destructuring it as data

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Could you bring more details? In my perspective it is a simple change in variable name - it is a variable with function scope

Comment: @Gleichmut its not a variable name within function scope, because `arguments` that you are getting in TodoList component is an object and destructuring has to match object key naming in order to extract

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean

Comment: yes its a change in variable name but its not about the function scope, in TodoList you are destructuring the parameters you received, as props is an object that is passed to your TodoList component and destructuring object need the property name to be exact, hope it clarifies

Comment: @Gleichmut you can accept the answer if it helped you, cheers

Answer (score 1):

As other solution/answer mentioned you were not destructuring properly thus you encountered the error.

Apart from above solution you can alias it for local scope name `data` as below:

```
const TodoList = ({todos: data, remove}) => {    // <---------------------
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
  let source = data.map((todo) => {
    return (<TodoItem todo={todo} id={todo.id} remove={remove}/>)
  }) 

  return (<ul>{source}</ul>)
}
```

You are getting an object in TodoList which happens to be your `props` which you are trying to destructure which has to match key by key but you can alias is using `:` for local name scoping generalized purpose.